# Append leading zeros in jstl tag when the value is less than 10

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a select element in my jsp view. I want that when the value is less than 10, it appends `0` before the number so `1` will be `01`. So far this is my code:

```
   <select id="sample" name="sample">
      <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="10">
         <option value=${i}>${ i<12 ? "0"+i  : i} hour</option>
      </c:forEach>
   </select>
```

When I run my code I get a error `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:`. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EL, the `+` is an addition operator, not a string concatenation operator. The string concatenation operator is only available since EL version 3.0 as `+=`.

However, you don't need it here. Just inline two expressions like below:

```
<option value="${i}">${i < 10 ? '0' : ''}${i} hour</option>
```

Note that I also fixed the logic error.

Comment: You are great. Very good java programmer. I read some of ur articles before

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `fmt` taglib:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
...
<option value="${i}"><fmt:formatNumber type="number" minIntegerDigits="2" value="${i}" /> hour</option>
```